# How to find spectrum of the operator below

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I'm trying to find spectrum of the operator $H=P^{2}-3P+I$ where $P$ is a projector.

I find a solution $\{-1,1\}$ but i'm not sure if i'm right.

Any different solution?

Comment: That's right. This is just an application of the spectral mapping theorem with $f(z) = z^2 - 3z + 1$.